# Viewing PyDoc with code completion

Tags: eclipse, pycharm, pydoc

[image]

Above is PyCharm and below is Eclipse with PyDev.

How do I show the PyDoc tooltip along with the autocomplete window like in Eclipse+PyDev? I've seen a few screenshots of PyCharm which show exactly this (eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbiQ.png)  but I cannot figure out how to make mine work this way. I tried IDE Settings>>Editor>>Code Completion>>Auto popup documentation in ms, set it to 0, but it seems to have no effect, I still have to press Ctrl-Q to view the PyDoc.

Answer (score 3):

This feature works only on the explicit code completion (when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to start the completion). It will not appear on automatic code completion. Settings dialog mentions it:

[image: explicitly invoked only]